# More efficient and faster query of updating IDs

Tags: sql, postgresql

Database PostgreSQL 9.6.4 (package created from slackbuilds.org). Two tables as below, only table `a` has Primary Key on `a.newid`, no constraints/indexes on table `B`. I need to update `b.aid` with values from `a.newid`. The question is if it is possible to do it in more efficient and faster way than I did as anonymous block (my extremely advanced code below). With my advanced solution it takes some time (about 10 minutes for 1M of rows in table `b`).

```
a.oldid a.newid
1       1
2       2
3       3
7       4

b.aid   b.desc
1       d1
2       d2
3       d3
7       d4

BEGIN
     FOR i IN SELECT newid FROM a
             LOOP
                     oldid := (SELECT a.oldid FROM a WHERE a.newid = i);
                     UPDATE b SET aid = i WHERE aid = oldid;
             END LOOP;
END
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: `WHERE a.newid = i` is incorrect syntax (it might only work due to implicit typecasting). The loop variable `i` is a _record_, not a single integer variable. So the correct way to reference the value of the column `newid` inside your loop is `i.newid`. See the examples in the manual for details: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for the comment I will read the maunal to avoid such mistakes in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do that without a loop:

```
update b 
  set aid = a.newid
from a 
where a.oldid = b.aid;
```